# Mirror all Stack Exchange pages where you were active

Tags: feature-request, export

I would like to have a working offline version of all questions I worked on, including questions I have commented on, edited, voted up,...

I know, you can export your data from each Stack Exchange site, using 
http://data.stackexchange.com

But how can you mirror all pages on all stacks where you were active?

I tried using `wget -m`  on my Stack Exchange profile site in the "activity" view, but that didn't work correctly.

It would be perfect, if the export were still working html sites that are linked between each other whenever possible. Also the side bar with "related questions" should be working.

Comment: Looks like you got a mess of questions here. Please focus on one request and elaborate what exactly you want to be done.

Comment: I added a summary

Comment: An offline mess of questions is still a mess of questions

Comment: It shouldn't be a mess. If i have a local folder I could search through it for keywords. and I would have a backup of all the work I have done, which is a lot of important documentation I accumulated here already

Comment: Also deleted questions would be an interesting point.

Comment: Is this something that will work for you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269951/158100

Answer (score 6):

You can get the posts you have asked, answered or commented on through queries in the data explorer, no need for `wget`. That would make retrieving the side bar not possible, which isn't useful in my opinion.

Some queries:

- [All your questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/341226/downloading-all-my-questions-with-the-answerer-names)
- [All your answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/2467/all-my-answers)
- [All your comments](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/30334/my-comments)

Of course you can still get the HTML through the post IDs.

Comment: Interesting, but it returns only 494 results for me, and I have.... way many more.

Comment: On which of the query? In fact, the queries are just samples of the possibilities of SEDE. OP can change the queries according to his wishes.

Comment: Oops, first one - thought it's for all activity in one place. So all is good. :)

Comment: This is not enough. I would need the whole question with all answers, when I added comment there or just did anything in that question

Comment: So you can combine all together in one right?

Comment: but then I wouldn't have the other questions and answers on questions where I provided just one answer. I want to have backupped the whole HTML page like it is visible in Firefox for all activities I ever did. This might get large, but it is worth it

Comment: I think a solution to this is still needed. also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158546/how-do-i-backup-my-stackexchange-favorites-for-offline-use

Comment: I would love to supply you with a better solution by I haven't one. I am sorry. @rubo77

Comment: What about deleted items?

Answer (score 3):

A solution to get at least all first 10 pages of questions and answers as browseable html pages:

```
#/bin/bash

# your User and Stackexchange ID from your "Network Profile" page
SE_ID=1047481
U=rubo77

mkdir -p stackexchange
cd stackexchange

# get all user ids across SE sites
users=$(curl https://stackexchange.com/users/$SE_ID/$U?tab=accounts|grep account-container -A1|grep http|cut -d"/" -f3,5|xargs)
for i in $users; do
  site=$(echo $i|sed "s~/.*$~~g")
  id=$(echo $i|sed "s~^.*/~~g")
  for a in questions answers; do
    for i in $(seq 10|xargs); do
      URL="http://$site/users/$id/$U?tab=$a&sort=newest&page=$i"
      echo "################### $URL #######################"
      wget -c -r -l 1 --wait 0.1 --random-wait -e robots=off -p -k -H "$URL"
      # sleep timer has to be added here to prevent a rate limit trigger of SE
      sleep 15
    done
  done
done
```

[explain wget options](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=wget+-c+-r+-l+1+--wait+20+--random-wait+-e+robots%3Doff+-p+-k+-H+%22%24URL%22)

This solution works quite well, before adding the sleep timer between downloads, it triggered the rate limiter on stackoverflow after about 80MB of sites downloaded:

```
Too many requests
```

But it fails to download the stylesheets, [this is the current result](http://r.z11.de/stackexchange/unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166525/download-all-pages-linked-on-a-page-in-a-certain-region)

How do I also download it with the correct CSS linked locally?

Comment: In general when scraping pages on SE I go with 5 second intervals and it seems to treat me well, most of the time.

Comment: a sleep timer after each wget call wasn't enough, I added ` --wait 0.1 --random-wait` to the wget call so it waits randomly 0.05 to 0.15 seconds between each download call in the recursive scraping. (This makes it quite slow, because also the page requisites are downloaded with that delay)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Readme at

https://github.com/rubo77/StackExchangeBackupLaravelPHP/tree/readme

then add the changes from my PR: https://github.com/ryancwalsh/StackExchangeBackupLaravelPHP/pull/10

This will create a one-pager with all links to all SO sites, you were active on and download this one-pager with depth 1